# Streams in Scheme

Tags: stream, scheme

How does the following process work:

```
(define integers
  (cons-stream 1 
     (stream-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) 
        integers))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important thing to realize here that only those expressions are evaluated which are neccessary to calculate the element of the list you're accessing.

So when you access the first element, it evaluates the first argument to `cons-stream` which is `1`.

When you access the second element, it evaluates the first element of `stream-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) integers`. For that it needs to get the first element of `integers` which is `1` and then adds `1` to that and you get `2`.

When you access the third element, it evaluates the second element of `stream-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) integers`. So it takes the second element of `integers` (`2`) and adds `1` to that to get `3`. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The reason that it takes only the second element of integers is because we are using "stream-map"?

Comment: @Nir: Yes, since all the stream functions are lazy it only takes as much as it needs to take give you the elements you requested.